# Typecasting NULL pointer in C

Tags: c, windows, struct, null

I have a structure

```
struct detail {
int id;
uintptr_t init;
// blah blah
};
struct detail info;
info.id = 1;
info.init = (uintptr_t)NULL;
```

I have to make the the `init` member NULL. What may/may not happen if I typecast(or do not typecast) `NULL` ? What if I directly assign it NULL like `info.init = NULL;` Does it make any difference with respect to runtime errors. It compiles fine. But the execution of the code is my main concern.

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to mention your target operating system and processor. You could code `info.init = 0;` which is almost always the same. Current systems almost always have the `NULL` pointer represented as an all 0 address (so an all 0 `uintptr_t`). In the previous century, there have been some bizarre, uncommon, exceptions to that (but at that time `uintptr_t` did not exist). And typecasting does not change generated machine code for source and destination of the same size [except for floating point].

Comment: Intel Pentium dual core/ compiling with VS2010

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch So you mean to say that using `info.init = (uintptr_t)NULL;` or `info.init = NULL;` won't make a difference

Comment: Yes, that won't make a difference, and you'll better code `info.init = 0;` almost every system have a `NULL` pointer which is a word with all bits cleared (but the C standard has wordings to permit very rare systems on which this might have been false; I cannot name any one relevant today; but that did happen in the previous century for very strange systems I never seen....)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Please don't confuse NULL representations in memory with the representation in code. The representation of a `NULL` pointer might be a `0xdeadbeef`, but that just means the compiler needs to translate so that `0`  in a pointer context becomes `0xdeadbeef` when writing, and vice versa. I would recommend using `NULL` for clarity, it's the standard in C.

Comment: We are not in a pointer context, but in an `uintptr_t` which is some *integral* type of the same size as `void*`; so `0` is probably more appropriate than `NULL`; I knew the (theoretical) difference between `NULL` and 0, but that don't matter today in practice on most systems!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: in the context of Windows, NULL is not a null pointer, it is a macro defined as 0.

Comment: @unwind: unfortunately, since Visual Studio (and the Windows SDK) do not respect that particular standard, the result may be less rather than more clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no guarantee in the standard that if `ptr` is a null pointer, then `(uintptr_t)ptr` is `0`.

If you don't care about systems on which null pointers and zero integers aren't equivalent, then `info.init = 0;` is fine.

The `init` member has integer type, it cannot be "made null". You can assign `0` to it, or you can assign to it the result of converting a null pointer to `uintptr_t`. On almost every C implementation ever, those are the same thing. But it is not guaranteed, and there have been systems on which it is not the same.

`NULL` might be a null pointer, or it might be an integer constant `0`. In the latter case, there *is* a guarantee in the standard that `(uintptr_t)(NULL)` is `0`. So there can be implementations on which `info.init = NULL; (void*)(info.init);` has undefined behavior. It wouldn't result in a null pointer if the integer equivalent of null isn't 0, and computing an invalid pointer value is UB.

So, if you want to guarantee that `info`, when converted to a pointer type, results in a null pointer then for true portability you should do `info.init = (uintptr_t)(void*)(NULL);`. You could optionally give the reader an extra clue by including the pointer type that the `uintptr_t` is going to be converted to, instead of `void*`. There are very few good reasons for storing a `uintptr_t`, so hints what is going on might help the reader.

Note that there is a guarantee in the standard that a zero-valued constant expression, converted to pointer type, is a null pointer. This does *not* imply that a zero-valued non-constant expression, converted to a pointer type, is a null pointer. Neither does it imply that a null pointer, converted to integer type, is 0. Those last two things happen to be true in most implementations (including all "modern" ones).

Comment: Agree in theory, but not in practice. I believe that it is really hard to code a standard C99 compliant real-sized program for a hardware on which `NULL` is not 0, but e.g. `0xdeadbeef` at the machine level. (and the compiler will probably also be buggy!)

Comment: No `uintptr_t` is some integral type (and you could multiply it by some small constant)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: It's not beyond the wit of man to write either the program or the compiler. For the program, you have to avoid errors like initializing pointer data with `memset`. For the compiler, you might need a special-case for when constant integer expressions are converted to pointer type.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I was confused; you are right. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: sure, the practice is covered by "if you don't care about..." in my answer. Perhaps I should make that more prominent.

Comment: +1, but there may be a catch here; if the rest of the code treats `info.init` as an integer to be compared to 0 (or, equivalently in this case, to `NULL`) then doing the right thing might just cause confusion, or conceivably break if built on a compiler which does not convert a null pointer to zero.  (The Windows SDK defines `NULL` as 0 rather than as a null pointer.)  So although this is the best answer given no other information, the programmer does need to take the specific context into account.

Answer (score 2):

NULL is a built in constant with a value matching whatever a null pointer is on your system. It's perfectly valid to assign the constant value to an int the same size (or bigger) than a pointer on your system.

Comment: In C99, `NULL` is a macro defined in `stddef.h` to be a null pointer; in Visual Studio it is a macro defined to be 0.  In neither case is it a built in constant.

Comment: -1 This is incorrect. `NULL` is a macro that *must* be defined to be `0` (or to `(void*)0`), and the compiler *converts* `0` in a pointer context to the null pointer constant.

Answer (score 0):

I would vote for the cast here, since assigning pointers to integers is generally not allowed and will generate a warning. It's a very good idea to use `intptr_t` of course, since it's big enough.