# char var[] = {0}; and char var[1]; are equivalent in C?

Tags: c, arrays, memset

what this line will do?

```
char var[] = {0};
```

Is this equivalent to the following?

```
char var[1];
memset(var, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: no, they aren't. the second one doesn't compile.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant , The `memset` is useless isn't it?

Comment: @CoolGuy memset's 3rd parameter is the number of bytes to write, and not a pointer. if the `NULL` pointer constant happens to be 0 on OP's platform, **and** the compiler doesn't choke on the implicit pointer-to-integer conversion, then the `memset()` is ineffective and the variable is left uninitialized.

Comment: Related: [what is the difference between struct {0} and memset 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031727/what-is-the-difference-between-struct-0-and-memset-0/14031737#14031737)

Comment: Rolled back to original question. Let's not put our own words into OP's mouth.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant the null pointer constant *must* be `0`, or an ICE that evaluates to `0`, optionally cast to `(void *)`.  So this code is either ill-formed, or sets zero bytes.

Comment: @MattMcNabb The null pointer constant, when converted to an integral type, may not have the numeric value zero. (in fact, since all pointer-to-integer conversions are implementation defined, it may have any value which, when converted back to a pointer, yields a null pointer.)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Rephrasing as it was apparently unclear. There are two cases of null pointer constant: (a) an ICE evaluating to `0`,  (b) an ICE evaluating to `0` which is then cast to `(void *)`. (6.3.2.3/3).  In case (a) it *must* have value zero. Since it is of integral type already, "converted to integral type" makes no change. In case (b), the `memset` is ill-formed because a pointer is not implicitly convertable to `int`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I think we are talking about different issues. Obtaining a null pointer from a null pointer constant does need to be done using an integral constant of value 0. The representation of pointers and pointer-to-integer conversions, however, are implementation-defined. Thus, the value obtained by converting *any* pointer (including the null pointer) to an integer is implementation-defined. Put differently, you muse use `0` (and co.) in a pointer context in order to acquire a null pointer, but `(int)NULL` may not have the numeric value 0.

Comment: @MattMcNabb [(see this answer in particular.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429372/typecasting-null-pointer-in-c) (and yes, I do realize that this is not true when `NULL` is simply an integral constant of value 0 *without* an explicit cast to `void *`. I'm addressing the case when its definition includes a cast.)

Answer (score 3):

`char var[]` will define `var` as a char array where size is decided by the initializer list size.

So `char var[] = {0}` is equivalent to `char var[1] = {0}`.

In your later code snippet, `var` may be uninitialized first (if a local variable, which I believe it is as it is followed by `memset`) and is then set to all zeros.(assuming you meant `memset(var, 0, 1)`) Although the observable effect of the both snippets are same, compiler may generate different instructions or compiler may choose to call the `memset` which may add function call overhead in later snippet.

Comment: in the second example, `var` is not initialized to zeros. it **could** be **set** to all zeros, **if** OP wrote the correct code for that.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant You are right, corrected.

Comment: Why did you change OP's code for your own purpose? It's strictly No-No here on SO. You should have explained clearly that point in your answer.

Comment: What will happen if I assign some value to it. i.e. more than 1 byte?
eg: strcpy(var, "some value");

Comment: int main()
{
 char value[] = {0};
 double dVal = 234.576;
 sprintf(value, "%f", dVal);
 strcat(value, "appending some test here");
 .....
 .....
}

Comment: @impulse `strcpy(var, "some value")` leads to undefined behaviour as you are overrunning the array size (`1` in this case)